# SelectOneMenu não é alimentado

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Tenho um `p:selectOneMenu` e gostaria que ele fosse alimentado com dados existentes no banco de dados assim que a página fosse carregada:

### pagina.xhtml

```xhtml
<p:selectOneMenu id="carros">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Carros" itemValue="0"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{menuManagedBean.carros}" var="carro" itemLabel="#{carro.modelo}" itemValue="#{carro}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

### MeuManagedBean.java

```java
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MeuManagedBean {

    private String modelo;
    private int codigo;
    private ArrayList<MeuManagedBean> carros;
    //getter-setter

    @PostConstruct
    public void attCarros() {
        carros = new CarroDAO.metodoDAO();
    }
}
```

### CarroDAO.java

```java
public class CarroDAO {
    //conexao...
    public ArrayList<MeuManagedBean> metodoDAO() {
        ResultSet rs //...
        ArrayList<MeuManagedBean> carros = new ArrayList<MeuManagedBean>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            MeuManagedBean carro = new MeuManagedBean();
            carro.setCodigo(rs.getInt("cdCarro"));
            carro.setModelo(rs.getString("nmModelo"));
            carros.add(carro);
        }
    }
    //...
    return carros;
}
```

Quando acesso a página nada aparece no `p:selectOneMenu`. O que eu tenho que consertar para fazê-lo funcionar?

---

Percebi um comportamento muito estranho. Todas as vezes que tento adicionar um método que é imediatamente chamado na página (i.e. com uma anotação `PostConstruct` ou no próprio construtor) ele não funciona.

Quando eu coloco um objeto "MeuManagedBean" dentro do `ArrayList` carros manualmente (pelo construtor utilizando `carros.add(MeuManagedBean)`), ele aparece no `p:selectOneMenu`.

Comment: MeuManagedBean precisa ter um getCarros()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-with-complex-objects-entities-from-a-db

Comment: @NilsonUehara, ele está lá, só não tinha colocado.

Comment: @JoãoManolo, então o método com `@PostConstruct` deve ser o `init()`? Não pode ser o `attCarros()`?

Comment: @Patrick Quando vc fiz que o `@PostConstruct` não funciona, o que exatamente ocorre? Ele não é executado ou o valor recuperado não aparece na lista? Se não verificou isso, veja se está pelo menos passando por essa linha.

Comment: @utluiz Ele não aparece na lista, porque os outros métodos da mesma classe funcionam.

Answer (score 1):

**MeuManagedBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="meuManagedBean") 

@RequestScoped 
public class MeuManagedBean {

//code...
public List< MeuManagedBean > getCarros(){

       return new CarroDAO().metodoDAO();
}
```

**pagina.xhtml**

```
<f:selectItems value="#{menuManagedBean.carros}".../>
```

Repare no nome que você referencia o Bean esta menu e não meu.

**Dica:**
*Renomeie os métodos de acordo com a função deles, troque `medotoDAO` por `getCarros` ou `listarCarros`.*

Comment: Parece que você está confuso quanto à formatação de perguntas/respostas/comentários. De uma olhada [neste artigo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Procure colocar explicações junto às respostas, além de ficarem de fácil entendimento, a probabilidade de ganhar reputações positivas e uma marcação como resposta aceita também aumentam.

Comment: Estou com um problema ao responder alguns trechos nao estavam saindo corretamente e nem apareciam. Estou editando aos poucos. Se voce puder editar e verificar se o problema acontece com vc tbm, a linha onde está < f:select nao consigo se eu juntar o caracter < a linha some

Comment: Sugeria a segunda opção, para o nome do método: `listarCarros()`. O `getCarros()` passa-me a impressão que retornas um atributo da classe.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que vc deveria criar uma classe Carro com os atributos modelo e código; o Managed Bean gerencia as requisições da página.
Quando a página é criada ela cria uma instância do Managed Bean e vc está criando vários objetos MeuManagedBean no CarroDAO e deveria ser o objeto Carro

Assim:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    Carro carro = new Carro();
    carro.setCodigo(rs.getInt("cdCarro"));
    carro.setModelo(rs.getString("nmModelo"));
    carros.add(carro);
}
```

E criar um converter para conversação do objeto itemValue="#{carro}" senão dá erro